# How to write mockito test for DAOImpl class

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I have a Dao Impl class that is responsible for updating the user details in the database. I am new to mockito so i would like to know how to write mockito test for this Dao impl class. The details of the function implementation is given below

```
public boolean updateUserDetails(UsersModel user) throws IOException {
        Properties properties = SqlProperties.readFromPropertiesFile();
        jdbcTemplate.update(properties.getProperty("updateUserDetails"), new PreparedStatementSetter() {

            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
                ps.setString(1, user.getFirstName());
                ps.setString(2, user.getLastName());
                ps.setString(3, user.getContactNumber());
                ps.setString(4, user.getUserName());

            }
        });

        return true;

    }
```

Comment: check this
https://howtodoinjava.com/best-practices/how-you-should-unit-test-dao-layer/

Comment: But this doesn't really speak about code coverage. And i guess this method is based on junit and not mockito and more over this doesn't increase my code coverage